# Typescript Interface Flattening

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have the following Typescript interface:

```
export interface Teammate {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  user: {
    email: string;
  };
}
```

That's how it comes from a GraphQL server, and I can't seem to "transform" it using Apollo Client. My question is, can I somehow create an `email` attribute of the above interface that would automatically "copy" the value from the nested attribute?

...as follows:

```
export interface Teammate {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: <= a function/Typescript method to copy user.email somehow over here?
  user: {
    email: string;
  };
}
```

Thanks,
Sammy

Comment: You are trying to transform a value or the type itself?

Comment: I'm trying to make `Teammate.email` hold the value of `Teammate.user.email`.

Comment: You can't do that with the type system if that is what you mean. Can you clarify your use of the term "attribute"?

Comment: If not using Typescript, any other way? Like a function maybe? What I mean by attribute is simply the interface member: `email`, `id`, etc.

Comment: Oh. Yeah you can write a function that takes care of it and understands the relationship between the properties

Comment: I can't imagine how I may do this, making the interface attribute reference other attributes of the same interface?

Comment: I'll try to add an answer later